# Laravel 7 orWhere mixed with and

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i wish to add an and condition to an existing orWhere line. I'm not sure if that's even possible. Here's the code.

```
 return $builder->whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) use($tagId) {
                $query->where('tags.name', 'verification')->orWhere('tags.name', 'pending')->orwhereNotNull('assigned_to');
            });
```

So what i want is at the end the orwhereNotNull part i want it to be like (orwhereNotNull('assigned_to') and condition) for those 2 only. So overall the code is like

```
$query->where('tags.name', 'verification')->orWhere('tags.name', 'pending')->(orwhereNotNull('assigned_to') and condition)
```

Comment: You can group the orWhere calls https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return $builder->whereHas('tags', function(Builder $query) use($tagId) {
    $query->where('tags.name', 'verification')
          ->orWhere(function($q1) {
              $q1->where('tags.name', 'pending')
                 ->where(function($q2) {
                   $q2->whereNotNull('assigned_to');
                   // your condition you want to use
                });
          });
});
```